# How can I align graphics horizontally across the whole page?

Tags: ieeetran

I am using the following document class / [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnRxfm.png):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}
\lipsum[2-2]
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

And get this as standard output:

[image]

How can I rotate the graphics to get the following output (I want to make my images bigger by arranging them horizontally):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Did you try `figure*` environment for figures spanning both columns and the option `angle` in the `includegraphics` command to rotate the images? However, if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), you may get better help.

Comment: While rotating the image is fine, I would check with the publisher before rotating the caption.

Comment: I have added some reproducible example to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a figure spanning both columns use the `figure*` environment. And to rotate the image, use the optional `angle` argument in the `includegraphics` command. A positive value of angle will rotate the image counterclockwise whereas a negative value will do the opposite. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum

\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=0.8\textwidth,angle=90]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Rotated image}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Note: IEEE doesn't allow two-column figures on the 1st page.